# Doing all validation at once

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, validation, controls

When trying to validate controls on a windows form I realise the .validated() for each controls fires when the focus is lost.  Instead I'd like to validate only when the button is pressed at the bottom, how would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check all the validation condition in `Button_Click`

```
/// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtUserName.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter user Name");
        }
        else if(condition)
        {
         }
         ...........
    }
```

Comment: i believe the OP is talking about invoking his "validators" only on button click instead of on focus lost

Answer (score 1):

When you set the causesValidation property to true the .Validating (and later: .Validated) event fires when you leave the control. Set it to false or simply do not handle the event.

To do Form-level validation, handle the .Closing event (better than the Buttonclick) and write your logic there. No sense in calling the Validating event handlers.

Answer (score 1):

Set AutoValidate to AutoValidate.Disable and in button click event call the ValidateChildren() method (it will fire all "validating/validated" events). [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms158374.aspx)